# convert string to date type in php

Tags: php, date

I have 3 variable `$day` , `$month` and `$year` and I want to create a date variable with these 3 variables  in this fromat : `yyyy-mm-dd` in php.

`$year` variable is a persian year for example `$year= 1390`

this code works properly but not for persian date :

`date("d-m-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $fMonth, $fDay, $fYear));`

How I can do it ?

Comment: There must be a million duplicates of this question. Did you try searching? And what sort of values do those variables have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'd want something like this:

```
date("d-M-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

EDIT: Oops, sorry, fixed.

Comment: These arguments are [in the wrong order](http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

Comment: What part of it is not working properly?  Wrong order, or syntax?  I'll try to help you out.

Comment: Excuse me `norway28` , it is work properly,but my $Year is a persian year that it's maximum is 1390 , but this code return a minimum year : 1970

Comment: You can just alter you $year variable accordingly.  Perhaps it should always be decreased by X years?

Answer (score 4):

http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Usage:

```
$myTime = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete and, dare I say it, lazy!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by date variable but. You can try these.

[mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

`mktime(0, 0, 0, $date, $month, $year)`

or you can create a DateTime Object

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
```

or you can try [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) if you have strings in your variables.